# i can't change min date value on kendo datetimepicker mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

I have problem with "kendo datetimepicker". if i set min value like this:

```
.Min(new DateTime(2020,1,1,8,0,0))
```

i change minimum value of date, but time still starts since 00:01. If i set it like this:

```
.Min(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,8,0,0))
```

i change date and time, but i can't set date since today. I tried set year as "2020" and rest as DateTime.Month, and DateTime.Day, but that don't work. Next i tried to prepare datetime and set it like this:

```
.Min(new DateTime(preparedDate.Year,preparedDate.Month, preparedDate.Day,8,0,0))
```

But that don't work too.
Can someone tell me how i can set min time at 08:00?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the minimum you set applies to the date and time together. Each of the things you tried fails because of this.

If you use `.Min(new DateTime(2020,1,1,8,0,0))`, you can't pick a date and/or time before 8:00 on 1/1/2020. So 7:00 on 1/1/2022 is available.

If you use `.Min(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,8,0,0))` you can't pick anything before 8:00 today. However, 7:00 is available for tomorrow's date and also you can't pick anything after 8:00 on a past date.

What you can do is use the `change` event of the DateTimePicker to complete a custom check and set the value yourself if the check fails.

You can see a demo using Kendo UI for jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.802/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.2.802/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<input id="datetimepicker" />
<script>
  let currentDateTime = null;
  
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    change: function(e) {
      var value = this.value();
      
      if (value.getHours() < 8) { // Check if the hour is before 8:00
        this.value(currentDateTime); // Return to old value
      } else {
        currentDateTime = value; // Store new value
      }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```